# How to use Sumif on dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm formatted cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was hoping to get help for the following problem

A file I was asked to work on contains multiple data points between certain date & time stamps. I need to sum certain values if they fall between set points in time. To illustrate, consider the example below:

[image: Data example format issues]

Assume that the columns from left to right are A, B & C.
I also have 2 separate cells containing date/timestamps (let's say in D1:E1)

[image: Timestamp data]

All the cells are formatted using Custom formatting, DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM.
I want to add up all values from column C, if the timeperiods in A and B for that entry fall between the timeperiods in D1:E1. In other words, if the checked value in A is greater D1 AND the checked value in B is smaller than E1, THEN sum the value from C. For this I planned to use the `SUMIFS` function. For the example above, this should sum the values from C2 and C3, returning a value of 2,58

I wrote the function as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C10;A1:A10;">"&D1;B1:B10;"<"&E1)
```

However, it keeps returning #VALUE!. I can't seem to figure out where this is going wrong. Evaluating the formula tells me the error occurs at the `D1` part of the formula. I'm looking for either a solution to fix my `SUMIF` method or a different method/formula that yields the desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Update*
After some trying out some tips from the comments, trying out over 1 row to begin with, the formula now returns 0 instead of #VALUE!, using

```
=SUMIFS(C2;A2;">"&D1;B2;"<"&E1)
```

Desired outcome should be 0,75. Added a table for testing purposes below.

```
Column A            Column B            Column C
17/11/2020 14:18    17/11/2020 14:31    0,22
18/11/2020 05:08    18/11/2020 05:53    0,75
18/11/2020 05:16    18/11/2020 07:06    1,83
18/11/2020 13:03    18/11/2020 13:57    0,90
18/11/2020 13:12    18/11/2020 15:18    2,10
18/11/2020 14:42    18/11/2020 16:41    1,98
18/11/2020 15:20    18/11/2020 17:23    2,05
18/11/2020 16:58    18/11/2020 17:26    0,47
18/11/2020 17:38    18/11/2020 19:32    1,90
20/11/2020 14:33    20/11/2020 16:36    2,05

D1: 18/11/2020 03:44
E1: 18/11/2020 07:30
```

Comment: If you type `=value(d1)` in a cell what do you get?

Comment: @SJR that gives 44153,1555555556 as return.

Comment: So that seems alright. Have you checked you don't have any error values in any of your cells?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. If you have only 10 rows you could start your formula just looking at row 1 and then increase by 1 each time and see where it breaks. Or just copy the value formula across and down for every cell. Somewhere you must have a cell which is not recognised as a time.

Comment: After checking the values I set all the ranges to second row (sum value in C2 if value in A2 > value in D1 and value B2 < value in E1). Checking those agains the =VALUE() results, all criteria should return TRUE and in turn yield value from C2 as a result. However, it now returns 0 as result.

Comment: @SJR (Typo in previous comment, could no longer edit it) I tested the other cells to see if that would give more clarity: Value(D1): 44153.15556; Value(E1): 44153.312500; Value(A2): 44153,2138889; Value(B2): 44153,2451388890

Comment: That's progress I suppose. You might want to post a table of data here so someone can test it.

Comment: You should be able to post a table of values (as text) by posting it as Code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thx, just updated with a table containing my used information.

Comment: I get the desired result here with your formula. I suspect some or all of your data entries may be text in columns A&B (they seem to be left justified *at least in A, I can't tell about B* which supports that). Please, in some empty area of your worksheet, enter `=ISTEXT(A1)` and fill down 10 rows, then across one more column, and see if that returns TRUE or FALSE.  Also make the same check for `D1:E1`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Just checked all cells, A1:B10 all yield TRUE for =ISTEXT(). D1:E1 both yield FALSE for =ISTEXT(). So I think you discovered the cause of the problem :) , however I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Easily fixed, but how did the values get there in the first place?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No idea, the file was handed to me as is. I was then asked to perform some actions with it, among other the issue posted here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225093/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-yellow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, it seems the problem is that the dates in Columns A:B are text, hence the failure of the SUMIFS.

To correct the problem (asssuming your windows regional short-date settings are `DMY`)

- In some area of the worksheet, enter the formula:

  =--A1

Then fill down and across so as to encompass your entire table.

*This should convert your table to the numeric equivalents*

- Select this new table you just created and `Copy/Paste Special - Values`

*This removes the dependency on the original table

- Delete the original table using the `Clear` button (on the editing tab of the Home screen)

*This will change the formatting to General*

- Paste the previously converted values into the table area
- format the cells as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`